# Basic testing with Truffle (not changing contract's state)

Tags: contract-development, web3js, truffle, contract-debugging

I'm just starting to use Truffle to test this contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Basic {
    bytes32 value;

    function Basic() {
        value = "mcansado";
    }

    function getValue() constant returns(bytes32) {
        return value;
    }

    function setValue(bytes32 _value) constant returns(bytes32) {
        value = _value;
    }
}
```

The relevant test code is

```
it("Should set value to 40", function(done) {
    basic.setValue(40, {from:accounts[0], to:basic.address})
    .then(function(tx) {
      console.log(tx)
      //assert.isOk(tx.receipt)
      done()
    }, function(error) {
        assert.equal(true, false)
        console.error(error)
        done()
      })
  })
```

That test is followed by one to get `value`. I would expected to get 40 back but instead I get this output

```
Contract: Basic
0x7d32e47118fbc082af1350062f10efee2694ff15
    ✓ Should retrive deployed contract.
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ✓ Should set value to 40 (43ms)
mcansado // returns the value made by constructor, not 40
    ✓ Should return the value set as 40


  3 passing (114ms)
```

How can I send the new value in the test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your contract and your test:

**- Solidity Contract**

You must differentiate a call (readonly method) from a transaction (write method that change the state). The keyword `constant` is used to specify the method as readOnly which means that no state variables are manipulated.

Moreover, a transaction is always asynchronous because the transaction needs first  to be broadcast to the peer2p network, then mined by a miner, this could take time (especially on a real network such as testnet or mainnet).

So you can't expect any value returned when you send the transaction from outside (Web3 ans Truffle).

The contract would look like that:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Basic {
    bytes32 value;

    function Basic() {
        value = "mcansado";
    }

    function getValue() constant returns(bytes32) {
        return value;
    }

    function setValue(bytes32 _value)  {
        value = _value;
    }
}
```

**- Truffle Test**

Secondly, your test isn't correct because you can't expect a returned value from the transaction, you need to call `getValue.call()` after the transaction has been sent.

Another think, with `byte32` type, you must deal with hexadecimal value. So you must use web3 functions `web3.fromAscii`  and `web3.toAscii`.

Last point, you can directly call `Basic.deployed()` to get the deployed instance.

I adapted your test:

```
var Basic = artifacts.require("./Basic.sol");

contract('Basic', function(accounts) {

    var basic;

    it("Should set value to 40", function() {

        return Basic.deployed().then(function(instance) { // Get deployed contract
            basic = instance;

            return basic.getValue.call(); // call getValue function

        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log("#######################");
            console.log("result (hexa)=" + result); // in hexa
            console.log("result (ascii)=" + web3.toAscii(result)); // in ascii

            return basic.setValue(web3.fromAscii("40"), {from: accounts[0]}); // send transaction setValue function

        }).then(function(receipt) {
            console.log("#######################");
            console.log("transaction receipt");
            console.log(receipt);

            return basic.getValue.call(); // call getValue function

        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log("#######################");
            console.log("result (hexa)=" + result); // in hexa
            console.log("result (ascii)=" + web3.toAscii(result)); // in ascii
            assert.equal(web3.toAscii(result), "40");
        });
    });


});
```

And here is the result:

```
  Contract: Basic
#######################
result (hexa)=0x6d63616e7361646f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
result (ascii)=mcansado
#######################
transaction receipt
{ tx: '0x051654a9fc0aaeb44ff54229c31ab91e9ad9fe9b03da4498d978740e760d739c',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash: '0x051654a9fc0aaeb44ff54229c31ab91e9ad9fe9b03da4498d978740e760d739c',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x106da8c6862f2caf94d40cf866d4b9a61b9c7839d7608fab00e114700dc3eb93',
     blockNumber: 108,
     gasUsed: 26695,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 26695,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [] },
  logs: [] }
#######################
result (hexa)=0x3430000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
result (ascii)=40
```

I published the full project on [GitHub here](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/24897-basic-testing-with-truffle-not-changing-contracts-state) for more details.

Comment: This is insane, thanks for the detailed response! Learned a ton.

Comment: Very helpful comment, I was facing some of the same issues.  I'm not quite yet following why getValue.call() is used whereas setValue() is called directly.  Still, following this pattern of calling the function directly when I need a transaction worked for me as it does above.

Comment: Having the same problem, but with your solution i haven't been available to fix it. The test in Solidity work perfect, but in javascript the state variable won't change. https://github.com/work-in-blocks/echo-blockchain

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55583/truffle-javascript-tests-wont-change-contract-state-contract-state-wont-chang @gregmerril