# Truffle Javascript tests won't change Contract State (Contract State won't Change)

Tags: truffle, metamask, truffle-contract

I reviewed a similar answer but it didn't work. Right now I'm starting with an Example trying truffle, I did a small Echo project based on the Pet Store Box from Truffle. And i'm having some problems:

My contract is like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./strings.sol";

contract Echo{
    address public owner;
    string[] private history;
    using strings for *;
    string public s;
    string public lastMessage;
    uint public messageCount;

modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
}

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    lastMessage = "None yet";
}

function echo(string text) public returns (string) {
    history.push(text);
    lastMessage = text;
    messageCount++;
    return text;
}

function fullHistory() public view returns (string){
    string memory _history = "";
    for (uint i = 0; i < history.length; i++){
        _history = _history.toSlice().concat("||".toSlice()).toSlice().concat(history[i].toSlice());
    }
    return _history;
}

}
```

So my tests in solidity work perfectly, i received the new values when i check the history of commands:

```
contract TestEcho {
    Echo echo = Echo(DeployedAddresses.Echo());

    function testWeReceiveWhatWeSend() public {
        string memory testText = "HELLO";
        string memory returnedText = echo.echo(testText);
        Assert.equal(returnedText, testText, "Should receive the same");
//        Assert.notEqual(word_count, 0, "Should have receive more than one");
    }

    function testWeReceiveTheHistory() public {
        string memory testText = "HELLO";
        echo.echo(testText);
        string memory fullHistory = echo.fullHistory();
        Assert.equal(fullHistory, "||HELLO||HELLO", "Should receive something");
    }

    function testWeReceiveTheLastMessage() public {
        string memory testText = "THE SECOND";
        echo.echo(testText);
        string memory message = echo.lastMessage();
        Assert.equal(message, testText, "Should receive the last message");
    }

    function testWeReceiveTheMessageCount() public {
        uint msgCount = echo.messageCount();
        Assert.notEqual(msgCount, 0, "Should be more than 0");
    }
}
```

But in javascript, they fail in modifying the Contract State, the `history` array won't change ever. The same happens to me in the web. Maybe i'm missing something obvious for sure, but I've been with this for days without a solution:

```
contract('Echo', async (accounts) => {
const from = accounts[0];

it("should return the same that i sent", async () => {
    const instance = await Echo.deployed();
    const textMessage = "TEST";
    const text = await instance.echo.call(textMessage, {from});
    assert.equal(text, textMessage, "echoes");
});

it("should return full history", async () => {
    const instance = await Echo.deployed();
    await instance.echo.call(web3.fromAscii("TEST"), {from});
    await instance.echo.call("TEST", {from});
    await instance.echo.call("TEST", {from});
    const history = await instance.fullHistory.call();
    console.log("FULL_HISTORY", history);
});
}
```

**And for some reason that i do not know, Metamask stop asking me about spending some Gas when i use the echo function in the browser, i already check the port, and the network is correct, the account have funds, the only thing that changed was that i accidently uninstall METAMASK and install a new Version. Still that does not explain why the tests won't work**

i will apreciate the help possible

Comment: Change `await Echo.deployed()` to `await artifacts.require("Echo.sol").new()`. Also, not a must, but you might want to put it inside a `before` clause instead of inside each one of the `it` clauses (depending on how you want your test to behave).

Comment: @goodvibration same result

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!!, sorry for all the problems...

EXPLANATION:

When you are using web3.js, the form:

```
ContractInstance.method.call()
```

It's just for methods that are annotated as view, or are readonly, you can still use something else, but it won't change the Contract state. Instead you want to use:

```
ContractInstance.method()
```

Just a small detail. LOL